# Can LinkedHashMaps be used to create a DAWG data structure in java

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

I was searching if we could have a DAWG api in java which might be of high value to hobby-design optimizers like myself.

DAWG is directed acyclic word graph which is a highly memory-efficient mechanism to store words.

So if someone has any thought on DAWG java API or thoughts with respect to implementing DAWG using LinkedHashMaps, please answer this question.